# How to to do dictation from system-audio?

Tags: mac, audio, audio-conversion, macos-monterey

Mac Monterey: When I execute the command Edit/"Start dictation, " the small microphone appears. But as soon as I click my audio-player window to start playing my podcast to transcribe the played system audio, the tiny microphone disappears!

So how can transcribe (i.e., dictate) the SYSTEM AUDIO (i.e., any audio played on my Mac) to TEXT?

I have researched this with Google but only found the advice to use the dictation feature.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/92613/use-mac-os-x-dictation-on-a-file and  https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/300340/using-dictation-to-transcribe-audio-files-in-batch

Comment: The Soundflower website does not exist anymore.

Comment: Soundflower from https://en.softonic.com/download/soundflower/mac/post-download cannot be installed in Monterey because it does not come from a verified developer.

Comment: https://rogueamoeba.com/freebies/soundflower/ or alternatively https://existential.audio/blackhole/